# Typed text is not displayed in notifications

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I created an application that allows you to enter the content of the notification and select the date and time at which the notification should be displayed. Everything works fine, except that the text entered in EditText by the user does not appear in the displayed notification. How to solve it? Thank you in advance!

MainActivity

```
package com.example.kalendarz_2

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.DatePicker
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TimePicker
import android.app.TimePickerDialog
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.util.*



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Inicjalizacja alarmManager
        alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    fun showDateTimePicker(view: View) {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val initialYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val initialMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val initialDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val initialHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val initialMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(this, { _, year, month, day ->
            val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(this, { _, hourOfDay, minute ->
                setReminder(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute)
            }, initialHour, initialMinute, true)
            timePickerDialog.show()
        }, initialYear, initialMonth, initialDay)

        datePickerDialog.show()
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private fun setReminder(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute)

        if (calendar.timeInMillis > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            if (alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()) {
                val reminderIntent = Intent(this, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
                reminderIntent.putExtra("REMINDER_TEXT", "Treść przypomnienia")
                reminderIntent.putExtra("REMINDER_TIME", calendar.timeInMillis)
                val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this, 0, reminderIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )

                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.timeInMillis,
                    pendingIntent
                )

                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Notification set at: ${calendar.time}",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            } else {
                // Handle the case where the device doesn't support exact alarms
                Toast.makeText(this, "Device doesn't support exact alarms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter date from the future", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

ReminderReceiver

```
package com.example.kalendarz_2

import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.example.kalendarz_2.R

class ReminderReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("ReminderReceiver", "Received reminder broadcast")

        val reminderText = intent?.getStringExtra("REMINDER_TEXT") ?: "No content notification"
        val reminderTime = intent?.getLongExtra("REMINDER_TIME", 0) ?: 0

        Log.d("ReminderReceiver", "Reminder text: $reminderText")
        Log.d("ReminderReceiver", "Reminder time: $reminderTime")

        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

        if (reminderTime > currentTime) {
            showReminderNotification(context, reminderText)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Notification: $reminderText", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun showReminderNotification(context: Context?, reminderText: String) {
        val notificationManager =
            context?.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val notificationChannelId = "channel_id"
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, notificationChannelId)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText("Notification: $reminderText")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                notificationChannelId,
                "Notifications",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId(notificationChannelId)
        }

        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

ReminderService

```
package com.example.kalendarz_2


import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi

class ReminderService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("ReminderService", "Reminder service started")
        showReminderNotification(intent?.getStringExtra("REMINDER_TEXT") ?: "no reminder content")

        return START_STICKY
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun showReminderNotification(reminderText: String) {
        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val channelId = "channel_id"
        val channelName = "Reminders"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        val notificationBuilder = Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setContentTitle("Reminder")
            .setContentText(reminderText)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you have hard-coded the reminder text in your  setReminder method ?
reminderIntent.putExtra("REMINDER_TEXT", "Treść przypomnienia")

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a beginner and I don't really know how to change it... Could you tell me how to change it?

Comment: I change to this, but it still doesn't work:
    if (calendar.timeInMillis > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        val reminderText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etReminderText).text.toString()
if (alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()) {
            val reminderIntent = Intent(this, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
            reminderIntent.putExtra("REMINDER_TEXT", reminderText)
            reminderIntent.putExtra("REMINDER_TIME", calendar.timeInMillis)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0, reminderIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE

Answer (score 1):

- **First of all**, you have to get the text from the *EditText* where the user enters the notification's text. Let's assume that you have an **EditText** with an ID reminderEditText. You would get the text like this :

```
val editTextR = findByView<EditText>(R.id.reminderEditText) 
val userText = reminderEditText.text.toString()
```

- **Secondly**, pass the input text to the Intent :

```
reminderIntent.putExtra("REMINDER_TEXT", userText)
```

Method setReminder :

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
private fun setReminder(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.set(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute)

    if (calendar.timeInMillis > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        if (alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()) {
            val reminderIntent = Intent(this, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
            val editTextReminder = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.reminderEditText)
            val userText = editTextReminder.text.toString()
            reminderIntent.putExtra("REMINDER_TEXT", userText)
            reminderIntent.putExtra("REMINDER_TIME", calendar.timeInMillis)
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0, reminderIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )

            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.timeInMillis,
                pendingIntent
            )

            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Notification set at: ${calendar.time}",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Device doesn't support exact alarms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter date from the future", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

*Remember to replace R.id.reminderEditText with the actual ID of the EditText in your layout.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but it still doesn't work... The notification is displayed with the original text still

Comment: Interestingly, the text in the notification that I entered first when using this application is displayed

Comment: When I first started the application, I entered the text "aaa". Now, every time I set a reminder and type some text, a notification with the text "aaa" appears.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Where is mistake?